# checking/comparing imagebutton resources

Tags: android, image, resources

I need to know how to check how to compare or check for an image resource on an image button

First I setup the button.

```
button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib1);
button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
if( currentTime%2==0 ) {
    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
}
else {
    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smileyhit);
}
```

Later at some point I need to check if the image resource of the button is the smiley drawable and increase the score.

something like

```
if( button1.getImageResource() == R.drawable.smiley ) {
score = score + 1;
}
```

What should I do to compare that? I do not want to use tags. Please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ImageButton.setTag` and `ImageButton.getTag` to identify which image is currently in `ImageButton` background as:

```
if( currentTime%2==0 ) {
    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
    button1.setTag(R.drawable.smiley);
}
else {
     button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smileyhit);
     button1.setTag(R.drawable.smileyhit);
}
```

use `button1.getTag` to check current image:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(button1.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.smiley ) {
 score = score + 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use tags because in my program there are like 30-40 image buttons. Setting tags makes the code much more complex. I have given a simpler example above for simplicity.

Comment: @Devenom `my program there are like 30-40 image button` then how you are setting images in 30-40 image buttons? in same way after calling `setImageResource` method you need to call `setTag` to add id with button. just in one line code

Comment: I'm setting the same image for all those buttons actually. But at Random. For which ever button comes up I set the image for that button. Then later I check which button has the image.

Answer (score 0):

using setTag and getTag you can easily differentiate images.

```
    if( currentTime%2==0 ) {
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
        button1.setTag("smiley");
    }
    else {
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.smileyhit);
        button1.setTag("smileyhit");
    }

if(button1.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("smiley")){
score = score + 1; 
}
```

Comment: hi M Krishna, I want to avoid tags because there are many buttons and setting tags for them makes it complex.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain an array with `currentTime%2==0` in it for each button. One should not depend on the UI to retrieve the state of the app since the UI is recreated at several different points in the life-cycle of an app. All your data which determines the state of the app should be seperated from the UI.

**EDIT**
Okie.. as you say you have more images, i still would go through array or list rather than depending on UI to get the data.My method would be as follows,

1. Create `constants` for each Image resource with an `Int` value
    eg: `public static final int image1=1`;
2. create the int array for the number of images and maintain them with initial values.
3. Each time to you change the image change the corresponding array element accordingly.
4. To find out which resource is used, check the corresponding array element.
5. While restoring UI(like onResume) use the array to set the corresponding draw able resource.

Comment: I kinda understand you. But the way I'm using it in my app needs comparing/checking the Image Resource used by a particular image button in the app. There are many buttons and about 3-4 images. But I just included a simple code in my question to make the answer easier. Thank You though.

Comment: No Panther. I understand what you are saying. But I can't reveal what my app is about. Its more complicated. It specifically needs to check the image resource for a particular button. And another reason I need to check the image is because I have used tags and that has taken up an additional 1000+ lines of code. If I only get the code to compare/check the image resource I will be able to withdraw the unwanted code. Thank You though! I know you are really trying to help.

Comment: @Devenom Okie, the last thing you can do is override the `ImageView` and write your own custom function to set and retrieve the image resource. Guess this is the last way for it :-/